# Very low network impedance close to 13th harmonic frequency

Tags: filter, high-voltage, harmonics, power-grid

I carried out a frequency scan of an electrical network model with a proposed 220kV transmission line. Addition of this line lowered the system impedance to very low value (to 3 Ohms) at 13th harmonic frequency (or 650Hz). Impedance was seen from the 220kV bus where new line proposed to connect. 
What kind of impact will be on the electrical network with such low impedance if 13th harmonics presence?
Will it be act as a 13th harmonic filter? If so, where will this 13th harmonic current be flown?

Comment: Is your resonance differential, or common-mode?

Comment: I really don't have idea about differential or common-mode resonance. The resonance I am referring to is a series resonance (I guess!) at 13th harmonic order. This RLC circuit is made of complex network which contains hundreds of HV lines, transformers, few reactors and capacitors. So, when there is a 13th harmonic current present at this bus, what will happen? will this low impedance amplify the 13th current and where will this current go?